# Detecting bluetooth headset button press

Tags: bluetooth

I'd like to build a system whereby I keep a netbook in my backpack, a bluetooth headset in my ear, and any time I hit the "talk button" on the headset, it records a voice memo to the netbook.

This is a question for any platform...

How can I make an executable run whenever the TALK button on the BT headset is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You would be looking at Bluetooth SMART, or BLE.

A few points to note:

- No pairing is required. The headset broadcast and your netbook listens.
- Your headset has to support Bluetooth 4.0
- Mac OSX and iOS supports BLE under the Core Bluetooth Framework. For other platforms you would have to do some searching.